# Сatch error from fetch in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch

Now I have the following architecture. React Redux on the front-end, there is also Rails api. In the state of my application (Redux) I store users status (Authorized or not). When I make any requests through fetch, I always process the same errors and send the same header.

For example: If I have unauthorized error from server, I always dispatch reducer, which changes the user's status to unauthorized.

What is the best way to handle these errors in one place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First maintain a store for all action-reducers, make an action-reducer for user auth status.
For handling errors in one place, make an axios service (If you are using axios for HTTP) in 'services' folder.
The service can be like this

```
import axios from 'axios';    
var AxiosService = {
        getMethod,
        postMethod,
    }

    function getMethod(url, successCallBack, errorCallBack) {

        axios.get(url, {
            header: header
        }).then((data => {
            return successCallBack(data);
        })).catch(err=>{
            //IF ERROR TYPE IS 401 UNAUTHORIZED
            //DISPATCH HERE
        })
    }

    function postMethod(url, obj,  successCallBack, errorCallBack) {

        return axios.post(url, obj, {
            header: header
        }).then((data => {
            return successCallBack(data);
        })).catch(err=>{
            //IF ERROR TYPE IS 401 UNAUTHORIZED
            //DISPATCH HERE
        })
    }

    export default AxiosService;
```

In any component while fetching, just import AxiosService like

```
import AxiosService from '..address'
AxiosService.getMethod('my/rails/backend',data=>{},err=>{})
```

Comment: Can you suggest how to check error type in catch block when api call fails with 401?